# Selenium Parametrization

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have tried this following code to automate gmail,in the first function the browser is able to get the element till "Compose" and click on it but the next few elements like "to" , "subject" is not found ..i have specified the next elements in void mailSend() function , i am not sure why it does not read the next elements.

```
public class Example{
public static WebDriver driver;

@BeforeClass
public void before()
{

driver = new FirefoxDriver();

}

@Test(dataProvider = "Data-Provider-Function")
public void startup(String uName,String pass) throws Exception
{

    driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys(uName);
    driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys(pass);
    driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-" +
            "KE L3']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(4000);

}


@DataProvider (name = "Data-Provider-Function")
public Object[][] startupProvider() 
{
    return new Object[][]

            {

            {"selva.prokarma.test@gmail.com", "prokarma"}

            };


}

@Test(dataProvider="Mail Information")
public void mailSend(String to,String subject,String body) throws Exception

{
    driver.navigate().refresh();

    Thread.sleep(2000);



    driver.findElement(By.className("vO")).sendKeys(to);    
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.className("aoT")).sendKeys(subject);
    Thread.sleep(2000);     
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".editable")).click();
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@tabindex,'1') and contains(@frameborder,'0')]"))); 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body[@role='textbox']")).sendKeys(body);    
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();       
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='T-I J-J5-Ji aoO T-I-atl L3']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(4000); 
    driver.navigate().refresh();
    Thread.sleep(4000); 
}

@DataProvider (name = "Mail Information")
public Object[][] mailSendProvider() 
{
    return new Object[][]

            {

            {"selva.prokarma.test@gmail.com", "This is a Test Mail","Prokarma"},
            {"selva.prokarma.test@gmail.com", "This is Test Mail 2","Hello Automation King "},
            {"selva.prokarma.test@gmail.com","This is another Test Mail 3","Hello  Selva"},
            {"selva.prokarma.test@gmail.com","This is another Test Mail 3","Hello  SelvaKumar"},
            {"selva.prokarma.test@gmail.com","Hi How are you doing","Robotium Tasks to be followed"}

            };

}

@AfterClass
public void tear()
{
    driver.quit();
}
```

}

Comment: did u try it on new gmail UI where compose window within the same browser window???

Comment: YEs , i tried wid the new gmail only,, upto compose button elements are able to find and click but when it comes to the next function "mailSend" ,it says "element not found"

Answer (score 0):

I kept the wait as 60 secs and removed all sleep statements which are not at all required. and More over i tried everything in single test method.

```
public class Example2 {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void before()
    {

    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    }

    @Test(dataProvider="Mail Information")
    public void mailSend(String to,String subject,String body) throws Exception

    {

        driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("xyzy@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("*********");
        driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-KE L3']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.className("vO")).sendKeys(to);    
        driver.findElement(By.className("aoT")).sendKeys(subject);

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".editable")).click();
        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@tabindex,'1') and contains(@frameborder,'0')]"))); 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body[@role='textbox']")).sendKeys(body);    
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();       
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='T-I J-J5-Ji aoO T-I-atl L3']")).click();

        driver.navigate().refresh();
    }

    @DataProvider (name = "Mail Information")
    public Object[][] mailSendProvider() 
    {
        return new Object[][]

                {

                {"xyzy@gmail.com", "This is a Test Mail","hello"},
                };

    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tear()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }
```

Attaching the output screenshot as well...
[image]

Comment: I have worked and implemented for iframe , now my doubt is ..y element is not able to read fom the second fucnction.. try running my code by installing testng jar and al u vil know///.. without using "data provider " i am able to run properly and get the elements after "compose mail"

Comment: Edit the username and password wit your account and give a try . u vil know what error it comes

Comment: can u please append the error stack trace, (will b easy to guide)

Comment: btw i tried the same code and it was working perfectly for me....check my answer for the code i used...